# Transfer function for Sallen-Key notch filter

Tags: operational-amplifier, filter, impedance, transfer-function, nodal-analysis

How can I find the transfer function H(s) of the following circuit by using impedance of the circuit?

Should I instead do it by nodal analysis?

[image]

Comment: Is this homework or a need for a practical application? I would personally use the fast analytical circuits techniques or FACTs to obtain a *low-entropy* equation from which you can immediately infer poles and zeroes. I did almost a similar example in my book on FACTs but it is quite some work (see example p 341 in this [list](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/Book/List%20of%20FACTs%20examples.pdf) from my webpage).

Comment: @VerbalKint it's a homework :(. I will take a look

Comment: Have a look at this [example](https://books.google.fr/books?id=cRCx6S-o-gEC&pg=PA150&lpg=PA150&dq=twin+t+notch+filter+transfer+function&source=bl&ots=dVvqssfUjJ&sig=LAAC7jQzjtnJYdGyYhWn5LDNEio&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=1wccVfiDKMv7oQTKvIDwAw&ved=0CFsQ6AEwBjgK#v=onepage&q=twin%20t%20notch%20filter%20transfer%20function&f=false) in which the author solves the TF of a notch quite easily with conductances. Replace the op-amp by a gain block linking V3 to V5 by \$1+\frac{R_5}{R_4}\$ and it should simplify the sketch. This is brute-force algebra and you'll have to format the final equation to a notch TF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact "no shortcut" way (by assuming the opamp works ideally) is to replace the opamp and its feedback resistors with a controlled voltage source which outputs V5 = (V3)(R5 + R4)/(R4). That's an ideal non-inverting amp.

Write the s-domain nodal equations. You do not need one for V4, it was in the removed circuit. But you write 3 of them; for nodes which have voltages V1, V2 and V3. Assume the opamp +input current =0.

Then you eliminate from your (four) equations other voltages than Vi and V5. Ratio (V5/Vi) is your transfer function.

Prepare to work with complex formulas if you have the parts as variables.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation: Usage of the superposition principle.

1.) Set the output voltage V5=0 and find the voltage Vp1=f(Vin) at the non-inv. input node for the opamp.

2.) Set the input voltage Vin=0 and find Vp2=f(V5).

3.) Find Vp=Vp1+Vp2 and set Vp=Vn=V5*R4/(R4+R5).

Comment: There are other notch filters whith easier tuning requirements.